# Is there a way to conveniently preview a Visual Force Page in VS Code?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning

So I'm trying to switch my IDE from the Developer Console to VS Code. But the thing is that the changes we make to a lightning component or a vf page in the dev console reflect in seconds on the app or the page.

But if we use VS code for development, do we have to push our code again and again onto the org to see the changes or is there a way to preview the page or app directly from VS Code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way we can preview VF page in IDE. I don't think they have this feature in their roadmap either.

You need to either save it and then view the VF or need to continue with your existing approach for this situation.

Comment: any extensions or something?

Comment: @vedantgupta I don't think we have any such extension available.

Answer (score 2):

Yess!!just follow few simple step to install extensions listed in below link

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MohithShrivastava.dx-code-companion

then,open VF page code in VS code and click on more action button(it's located at right top corner(icon is ...).

then click on 'CCDX:open visualforce page' button.

you are there on your page!!

Best Regards

Nagesh

Comment: Did anybody test this methodology and confirmt that it works ??

Answer (score 0):

I found this as resource when you want to preview your VisualForce Page in VsCode:
It works for me after following these instructions on the next link.

https://medium.com/@idanblich/open-salesforce-pages-and-lex-app-directly-from-vscode-38e889e1759a

In the Link you will find instructions to add a tasks.json file in your project.
After taking the succesfull steps you will be redirected in a browserwindow to the preview page.

And after every deployment to your org. Simply refresh the page.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE @wakweyo. It's always best to include a bit of descriptive text with at least some of the details from the link you've provided in the event it should change at a later time. In doing that, the value of your answer won't be lost. Please edit your answer to include a bit about the Medium article you've linked to.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I edited my answer.